# PDF files on SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, pdf

Can I add books to my SQLite database in android??
If yes, how?
I want to put the books on database because I've too many books to add to the android app and I don't want to make the size of the Application too much.

Comment: SQLite support only primitive types.
Did you try to serialize the pdf into a string using Gson?

Comment: you can use it using base64 conversion

Answer (score 0):

> There's a limit of 1MB on internal assets due to dynamic decompression; the 1MB >limit also seems to apply to Cursor blobs but this doesn't seem to be >documented anywhere.
>
> Generally you should avoid blobs in SQLite as they perform poorly; instead, >save the blob data as a file and store the location of the file in your DB

I won't recommend storing pdf flies in SQLite, you can just provide a simple link to download it to the user. but if you want to store it here you can do something like this.
First, you need to convert the pdf file into a byte array

```
import java.nio.file.*;

Path pdfFilePath = Paths.get("/file/path/your_file.pdf");

// Read file to byte array
byte[] pdfByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(pdfFilePath );

// Write byte array to file 
Files.write(pdfFilePath , pdfByteArray);
```

You're looking for BLOB to store the data in android SQLite.

BLOB - The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Here's an example of making a table with two columns - an id and some data, which is a BLOB:
just for an example, you can create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data BLOB);
```

Comment: But my files are over 1MB each, can it be added to the assets folder?

Comment: It works for other more than 1 MB max 2MB in some scenario but you should avoid it. Use server to store your files
**Read this for SQLite blob** [link](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/sql-blob-field-size-limit-in-basic4android.27838/)

Comment: which server would be best for me?

Comment: you can use any file hosting or CDN to download and upload it. if you are just providing file service to the end user.or you can go for the node js to maintain the backend service

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it. you cant store files in SQLite database. You will store your files in asserts folder.

Comment: But I've over 200 files and over 1MB each, can it be added and what impact will it have on the size of the application?

Comment: Yes it will become big threat your application. It has lot of disadvantages. Better to store files in Server and fetch one or more whenever user need. It has some more advantages like you may add files at anytime once you add it server then app consume whenever no need to update app and app size definitely reduced.

Comment: And which server would be best for me??

Comment: I prefer Node server.